# How to trigger the change event of Kendo Jquery Spreadsheet when using custom Paste function?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendospreadsheet

I tried the below custom paste function to paste only values but it doesn't trigger the change event in order for me to sync the data to the data source.

[Dojo Demo Link](https://dojo.telerik.com/UMEpEkot)

```
...
change: onExcelChange,
paste: function(e) {
            e.preventDefault()

            var currentRange = e.range;
            var fullData = e.clipboardContent.data;
            var mergedCells = e.clipboardContent.mergedCells;
            var topLeft = currentRange.topLeft();
            var initialRow = topLeft.row;
            var initialCol = topLeft.col;
            var origRef = e.clipboardContent.origRef;
            var numberOfRows = origRef.bottomRight.row - origRef.topLeft.row + 1;
            var numberOfCols = origRef.bottomRight.col - origRef.topLeft.col + 1;
            var spread = e.sender;
            var sheet = spread.activeSheet();
            var rangeToPaste =  sheet.range(initialRow, initialCol, numberOfRows, numberOfCols);

            sheet.batch(function() {
                for(var i = 0; i < fullData.length; i += 1) {
                    var currentFullData = fullData[i];

                    for(var j = 0; j < currentFullData.length; j += 1 ) {
                        var range = sheet.range(initialRow + i, initialCol + j);
                        var value = currentFullData[j].value;

                        if (value !== null) {
                            range.input(value);
                            range.format(null);
                        }
                    }
                }
                 sheet.select(rangeToPaste);
            }, { layout: true, recalc: true });        
        } ...
```

I have tried to use recalc: true in sheet.batch to trigger the change to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

All Kendo widgets [inherit from Observable](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/widget), which has a [trigger](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/observable/methods/trigger) method:

```
var obj = new kendo.Observable();
obj.bind("myevent", function(e) {
    console.log(e.data); // outputs "data"
});
obj.trigger("myevent", { data: "data" });
```

You need to manually trigger the Spreadheet's [change event](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/spreadsheet/events/change) with its correct parameters.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried the above, the change event gets triggered now but datasource.sync doesn`t reflect the changes made on spreadsheet.